# Undo Git commit and resolve pull

Tags: git

I'm once again lost in the wilds of Git. This is all occurring within the context of Visual Studio 2015.

I moved a bunch of files to a new folder within a project. Apparently, this throws away all of the Git history for the moved files. I say this because when I do a `git log --` on any of the moved files it only shows the most recent activity, not all the stuff I've done over a period of several months.

Unfortunately, I discovered this after syncing the changes, and pushing the current state out to my remote repository.

I want to restore the environment to where it was before I moved all the files, and move them in a different way (I believe using `git mv` at the command prompt preserves the history, unlike when Visual Studio does it).

I tried doing:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

from the command line, which reverted the local files to the state I wanted.

But when I go back into Visual Studio I find that there's an incoming fetch pending. And if I make any other local changes and try to commit them I get told I can't do that because of that pending incoming fetch.

I tried reverting or resetting the incoming fetch. But all that does is take me back to the state where the files were moved within Visual Studio, and the commit history was lost.

I logged into the remote repository, and I can see that it contains the pushed changes I'm trying to revert. But they're not on the active branch, and I'm unsure of how to do a `git reset` on a non-active branch.

How do I get rid of that pending fetch?

**Additional information**

In working through Schwern's advice I discovered that the "lost history" was actually lost at a different stage of the process I was using. Here's what that involved.

I'm trying to extract some folders from the current Git repository, along with their history, so I can move them into a separate Visual Studio solution. That involves cloning the local repository into a new folder, cutting the new repository loose from its origin, and using `git filter-branch` to remove everything except the stuff you're trying to extract. You then pull the extracted stuff into a new Visual Studio solution -- which has its own, separate repository -- and you're good to go.

I've done this before and the history was preserved. But what I discovered today is that the history disappeared when I did the filter-branch:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter src/UploadProcessor/extract20170224 -- --all
```

In other words, doing `git log` before running filter-branch shows all the history I expected. Running `git log` after filter-branch shows only the most recent changes to the files.

Thoughts? Other than maybe I should just give up on trying to retain the history... :)

Comment: Oh no. Using `git filter-branch` to undo a single commit is like using a machine gun to swat a fly! All is not lost, `git reflog` can help undo the damage.

Answer (score 0):

**If your branch is at the state you want it to be locally and you are 100% sure of this you can**

```
git push --force
```

which will force the remote branch to be exactly like the local one.

### **WARNING:** This will overwrite any changes which have been pushed to the remote branch.

There are some alternative ways to fix this problem that you might consider.

1. Pull all the remote changes and then undo the actions you took in reverse and then push that as a new commit.
2. `git reset --soft HEAD^` or in Windows `git reset --soft HEAD~1` and then running `git push origin +branchName` which will undo the commit that moved the files.

Comment: DON'T DO A FORCE! Not without first understanding what's happened. You might have put your local repo in a bad state and this will just share that mess with everyone else. Right now the remote is your lifeline to sanity.

Comment: The question he's asking is how to undo the commit he pushed to the remote branch. I'm making a few assumptions while answering this question:

1. The local branch is in the state he wants the remote branch to be.
2. He's on his own fork of this project and nobody is working off of his remote branch.

If the above are true, there is absolutely no reason why he can't force push to remove the changes he made.

He can also pull the remote, do a rebase -i HEAD~2 and delete the disastrous commit and then git push --force-with-lease

All of these are safe if #1 and #2 are true.

Comment: Yeah, the assumptions and lack of explaining them so they could check them are the problem. I think I've worked out what's happened, and I think a force push is correct. Just mind giving that advice out willy-nilly. Anyhow, DV removed.

Comment: I don't believe I was giving that advice out willy-nilly. I felt I understood his problem and what he was asking. Thank you for your advice about my advice. I will explain more in the future. That's probably the safer path for potentially destructive git commands.

Comment: "Lack of explaining them" is a bit odd, IMHO. If someone knew enough to precisely and thoroughly describe a problem, the odds are they would've solved it without resorting to stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarkOlbert That was in reference to their original answer, not your question.

Comment: Ah, thanx. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

> *I moved a bunch of files to a new folder within a project. Apparently, this throws away all of the git history for the moved files. I say this because when I do a git log -- on any of the moved files it only shows the most recent activity, not all the stuff I've done over a period of several months.*

Git doesn't track renames, a `git mv` is a `git rm` + a `git add`. Instead it guesses based on the similarity of the files which has its advantages and disadvantages.

You often have to give it some encouragement. `git log` has various options to do that. `--follow` will follow the history of a single file beyond renames. `-C` will detect copies as well. `-M` will follow renames in diffs. `git blame` has similar options.

> *But when I go back into Visual Studio I find that there's an incoming fetch pending. And if I make any other local changes and try to commit them I get told I can't do that because of that pending incoming fetch.*

I don't know what Visual Studio is doing, and I don't know what a "pending incoming fetch" is or why it would be blocked by or block anything. ***`git fetch` is always safe.*** It only updates your remote tracking branches (ie. it updates your idea of what the remote repo looks like) and does not touch your local branches. A `git pull` is a `git fetch` + `git merge` and sometimes with a hairy pull it's useful to do it in two steps.

I *suspect* what's happening is Visual Studio is trying to treat Git like a traditional centralized version control system (like SVN) and make sure you're always committing to the tip of the branch. IIRC in SVN you had to `svn up` before you could `svn commit` and I suspect that's what Visual Studio is cryptically telling you to do. So it must always fetch and merge the latest version before you're allowed to commit. I suspect it's really going to do a `git pull`, not a `git fetch` and has got the terms wrong. If that's the paradigm you're shoved into, I guess let it.

This is why I recommend avoiding using Git GUIs for anything but visualizing the state of the repository: who knows what it's doing or what philosophy of version control they're trying to apply. Visual Studio is probably trying help by presenting Git via a more familiar version control paradigm. While that might help in the short term, shoving Git's square peg into SVN's round hole is just going to cause problems in the not-very-long run as I suspect you're experiencing right now.

---

Anyhow, for your current situation, what I think has happened is this.

1. You commit the mistaken change.
2. Visual Studio *immediately* pushes it to the remote, SVN style.
3. You undo the commit locally.
4. Visual Studio "helpfully" notices that you're a commit behind the remote (your own commit you've just undone) and, SVN style, will not let you commit anything else until you catch up... with your own undone commit.

That, BTW, is why you don't immediately push commits in Git. Half the point of a distributed repository is it decouples committing from sharing. So you can commit whenever is best without also sharing. And you can undo your mistakes, because they weren't shared in the first place.

So, assuming your local repo is in order, `git push --force` to force the repository to match your own ***assuming nobody else has committed anything else***. Then things should be in order.

***A safer thing to do*** is to allow the fetch/pull to happen, get the old commit back, and then undo your commit the conventional way that matches how SVN works: use [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). This will make a new commit that reverses another commit. Then you can push it normally.

And consider not using Visual Studio to control Git, or don't use any of the distributed features of Git.

---

> *I've done this before and the history was preserved. But what I discovered today is that the history disappeared when I did the filter-branch:*

Oh dear.

Ok, so, based on the updates to the question, and that `git filter-branch` has been run, their local repo is probably in an unknown state. Don't worry! That just means I can no longer predict what your repo looks like, I'd have to look at it to be sure.

The best thing to do is to get it back to its known state. There's two ways to do this.

***If you did not `git push --force`*** or otherwise commit changes (I'm still assuming Visual Studio pushes after commit) just clone a new copy of the repository. That'll return you to the state you were at just after the bad commit. Then `git revert` that commit. Done.

***Don't delete the existing repo!*** Just clone a new copy somewhere else. Keep the existing repo in case something goes wrong).

The more clever way to do it, and this works for almost anything that messed up the repo, is to use `git reflog` to find the last known good commit and reset to that. Git doesn't rewrite history, instead it writes new history and says it's what always happened. So your old commits are still there, for a while (like, weeks).

When you run `git reflog` you'll see something like this:

```
7efa9c7 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit: Testing 123
f999b32 HEAD@{1}: commit: #fo
7c6a630 HEAD@{2}: commit: # message with a comment
1a0bddf HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): First commit
```

That's all the time HEAD moved. HEAD is the currently checked out commit, so commit, reset, checkout, filter-branch, rebase... these will all move HEAD. The first column is where HEAD moved to. The second is a symbolic way to refer to that commit. Then the command used. And finally the first line of the commit message.

You're looking for something like:

```
deadbee HEAD@{?}: commit: The message of the wrong commit.
123abcd HEAD@{?-1}: commit: This is the commit you want to move back to.
```

Then `git reset --hard 123abcd` will return you back to the commit just before you made a mistake. Everything else you did after that will be wiped clean.

...***except*** you did a `git filter-branch --all` which affects ***all*** branches. So you might have hosed all your branches. `git reset` only affects one branch.

Again, don't use things like `git filter-branch` or `git-reset` or `git-rebase` without first understanding how Git is structured. It sucks, but you can get into a lot of trouble otherwise.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanx for the explanation. When I do a git fetch, whether from the cmd line or within VS, it completes, but the pending fetch is still shown. I presume that means there's still a difference between the remote and local "views"...which makes sense, as that's the problem I'm trying to resolve. But what I want to do, I guess, is undo what's on the remote repository. Thoughts?

Comment: @MarkOlbert I think I figured out what's going on and added an explanation.

Comment: @MarkOlbert A `git fetch` doesn't work because I believe what Visual Studio is calling a "pending fetch" really means it wants to do a `git pull` and not only fetch the changes, but also merge them into your branch. Anyhow, I'd suggest that you let the pending fetch happen, and then use `git revert` to undo the change. That'll produce a conventional commit to undo the change. The unwanted commit will still be in history, but that's the price you pay. Visual Studio's style of interacting with Git can cope with this better.

Comment: Thanx, I really appreciate your help educating me. Would you mind taking a look at my amended question? I discovered some additional info which may mean my problem of lost history involves something else.

Comment: @MarkOlbert Sorry, I don't see any edits to the question.

Comment: @MarkOlbert Well, you've hosed yourself pretty good. Don't worry, Git finds a way! Updated the answer. Good luck!

Comment: You're right, I would've..if I hadn't done a clone into a new directory of the entire repo, and then done a git rm remote on the clone so that it was disconnected from the original local repo. Fortunately, the directions I was following were very explicit about the need to do that. So my original local repo still has all the history.

Thanx again for all your help!

Comment: @MarkOlbert You can add the remotes back with `git remote add <name> <url>` and then refetch it with `git fetch <name>`.